# GDB Break if frame is in backtrace

Tags: gdb, conditional-breakpoint

I want to set a condition on a gdb breakpoint to only break if a certain function name appears in the backtrace. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to set a breakpoint in gdb that is conditional on the call stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336403/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-gdb-that-is-conditional-on-the-call-stac)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how to do exactly what you ask for, but a possible workaround, if you have access to the source code of the relevant function, is to set some global boolean variable to `true` in the beginning of the function, and set it to `false` just before the function exits. Then you could set a conditional breakpoint (using the `condition` command) to stop only when this boolean variable is `true`.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing but I would of liked to know how to do it without recompiling.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler solution than Python scripting is using a [temporary breakpoint](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_28.html).

It looks like this:

```
b ParentFunction
command 1
  tb FunctionImInterestedIn
  c
end
```

Every time you break in `ParentFunction`, you'll set a one-time breakpoint on the function you're actually interested in, then continue running (presumably until you hit that breakpoint).

Since you'll break exactly once on `FunctionImInterestedIn`, this won't work if `FunctionImInterestedIn` is called multiple times in the context of `ParentFunction` and you want to break on each invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to rix0rrr's answer:

```
b main
commands
set $inParentFunction = 0
c
end

b ParentFunction
commands
set $inParentFunction = 1
c
end

b FunctionImInterestedIn if ($inParentFunction)
```