# gdb: conditionally break on function only if the caller function is not equal certain value

Tags: c, linux, gdb

In my project, I have my_malloc() that will call malloc().

I like to set up the conditional breakpoint in gdb such that gdb will break into "gdb>" only when the caller function of malloc() is not equal to my_mallc().

Is it possible?

The goal is to id all that code that is calling malloc() directly and didn't go thru my_malloc().

Comment: Sounds like XY-problem to me. Why not `LD_PRELOAD` `malloc()`

Comment: @EOF,   my_mallc() is called from a C Macro that add addition info such as __FILE__, __LINE__ such that I can keep track of alloc/free amount for each file:lineno entry.   If I use LD_PRELOAD, I loss the __FILE__, __LINE__ info from the preprocessor.

Comment: @EOF - Could you give more details?  I'm afraid your answer assumes more knowledge than many people have.

Comment: equal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336403/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-gdb-that-is-conditional-on-the-call-stac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I like to set up the conditional breakpoint in gdb such that gdb will break into "gdb>" only when the caller function of malloc() is not equal to my_mallc().

In other words, you want to break on `malloc` when it is not called by `my_malloc`.

One way to do that is to set three breakpoints: one on `malloc`, one on `my_malloc` entry, and  one on `my_malloc` return. Then (assuming the breakpoints are 1, 2 and 3 respectively).

```
(gdb) commands 2
silent                # don't announce hitting breakpoint #2
disable 1             # don't stop when malloc is called within my_malloc
continue              # continue execution when BP#2 is hit
end

(gdb) commands 3
silent
enable 1              # re-enable malloc breakpoint
continue
end
```

This technique only works for single-threaded applications.

Comment: Thanks.  I will accept your answer.   It give me an idea which is setting a global variable g_from_my_malloc=1 in my_malloc() before calling malloc and clear it after malloc return.   This way, it is easy to break on malloc condition on if g_from_my_malloc!=1.    If I guard it with mutex, it should work on multiple-thread app too.    THANKS AGAIN!!!