# How to pass CLI arguments to a "commands" inside a "define" in GDB?

Tags: gdb

E.g.:

```
define mycmd
    break $arg0
    commands
        print $arg0
    end
end
mycmd myfunc
continue
```

Prints:

```
$1 = void
```

instead of the expected `myfunc`, because `$arg0` is evaulated when the command is hit, and since it has not been defined shows `void`.

Is there a way to pass it to the `commands`?

I think I would be able to do it with Python easily, but it would be cool to have a quicker way. But if you have the Python ready, just paste it anyways.

Motivation: automate https://stackoverflow.com/a/5372742/895245 , where I'd like to write:

```
define break-stack
    break $arg0
    commands
        tbreak $arg1
        continue
    end
end
break-stack ParentFunc ChildFunc
```

Yes, I know that https://stackoverflow.com/a/20209911/895245 provides a Python solution.

GDB 7.11, Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't coax gdb's `eval` to evalute multi-line commands such as `commands`, so here's a solution that uses `shell`.

```
define break-stack
  dont-repeat
  break $arg0
  shell { echo commands; echo tbreak $arg1; echo continue; echo end; } > /tmp/gdbtmp
  source /tmp/gdbtmp
  shell rm /tmp/gdbtmp
end
```

If your `echo` accepts the `-e` option, it can be shortened to

```
define break-stack
  dont-repeat
  break $arg0
  shell echo -e "commands\ntbreak $arg1\ncontinue\nend" > /tmp/gdbtmp
  source /tmp/gdbtmp
  shell rm /tmp/gdbtmp
end
```

Your specific task - stopping when function *b* is called by function *a* - can be done by using the `$_caller_is` convenience function, which is included in recent versions of gdb.

```
define break-stack
  break "$arg1" if $_caller_is("$arg0")
end
```