# GDB / C++ - Logging multiple variables to an output file based on a loop condition

Tags: c++, cmake, gdb

I am debugging a `C++` code using commandline `gdb` in `Ubuntu`. I have a `class A` with different functions `func1`, `func2` and `func3` each of which ends on lines `28`, `42` and `64` in the file `A.cpp`. The `func1` uses some local variables like `p1`, `q1` and class member variables such `a_r`, `a_t`. Similarly `func2` and `func3` have local variables such as `p2`, `q2` and `p3`, `q3`. The `func2` also uses another class member variable `a_s`. They also use some variables other than the ones mentioned here. Now these functions are called inside a loop with loop varaiable `l_num`.

I would like to log the above variables to a `.txt` file when `l_num` has a value between `10` and `20`. I tried:

```
set logging on
if (l_num >= 10 && l_num <= 20)
 >break A.cpp: 28
 >commands
  >print a_r
  >print a_t
  >print p1
  >print q1
  >end
 >break A.cpp: 42
 >commands
  >print p2
  >print a_s
  >end
 >break A.cpp: 64
 >commands
  >print p3
  >print q3
  >end
 >end
```

**But this threw an error: `No symbol "l_num" in current context.`**

I have `gdb version` = `7.11.1`, `gcc version`/ `g++ version` `5.4.0`. I am compiling using `cmake` in `Debug mode`. I have the following setting to turn off optimization:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -O0")
```

Then in the terminal, I compile using:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .
```

I am relatively new to `GDB`. Kindly guide on this problem.

**Edit:** It is not actually right to call `l_num` as loop variable. It's just a variable that is updated with every run of the loop. The loop actually is reading lines of a file and is exited when `EOF` reached.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if (l_num >= 10 && l_num <= 20)
>break A.cpp: 28
...
```

will only work if you have `l_num` in *current* context (i.e. if you are in the frame where variable `l_num` exists).

It will also not do what you want: if `l_num` is between 10 and 20, it will set (multiple) breakpoints at `A.cpp:28`.

What you appear to want is to set one breakpoint on `A.cpp:28`, but only enable that breakpoint when `l_num` is between 10 and 20.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5372742/50617) is an example of how to do somewhat similar thing, which can be adapted to your use case.