# Can GDB set a breakpoint on a sequence of function calls?

Tags: debugging, gdb, breakpoints, gdb-python

I'd like to inspect some global variables before a crash happens. The issue only reproduces on a certain stack trace and setting a breakpoint on the innermost function (or any other from the stack) will not get me close enough.

Can I achieve the result of breaking only when the top of the stack contains something like this ?

```
#0 __GI_connect
#1 curl_connect
#2 get_file
#3 init_assets
```

Just doing

```
b init_assets
c
b get_file
c
...
```

doesn't work since init_assets is called multiple times and it doesn't call curl every time, so gdb will break in unrelated code that uses curl.

Later edit: another way is:

```
b inner_func
ignore 1 10000
r
# app crashes
info b

Breakpoint 1 has been hit 10 times.
```

Then you remove the breakpoint, add it back and only ignore 9 times. When you run the app again, gdb will stop on the 10th time -- when inner_func crashes.

You can also record the app in mozilla's `rr` if the execution varies too much.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a conditional breakpoint with the the [`$_caller_is` convenience function](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Funs.html#index-_0024_005fcaller_005fis_002c-convenience-function).  Something like this:

```
(gdb) break connect
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7ffff7ee6820
(gdb) cond 1 $_caller_is("curl_connect") && $_caller_is("get_file", 2) && $_caller_is("init_assets", 3)
```

Comment: Wow! The `_caller_is` is convenient. Previous answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5372742/50617

Comment: Is it possible to use $_caller_is without debugging symbols, e.g. match it against the stack frame address?